# Display flash notices in various locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a temp;late with a menu down the lhs that has a search function to restrict the menu options.

Some times the user may search for an option that returns no results.

When the search returns no results I would like to display a flash notice above the search box to communicate this.

In addition to the menu flash i would also like to use flash to communicate the normal messages associated for form operations in the main part of the view such as record save, user logged in etc.

Is it possible to display multiple flash messages on the one view or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: are you using bootstrap flash?

Comment: not yet... :) I didn't know about it. Newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

i had resolved the same scenario using flash with ajax so that i can use id or class selector to update the html in any place in my app.

**show flash using ajax
add this in application_helper**

```
def flash_display
  response = ""
  flash.each do |name, msg|
    msg=msg 
    response = response + 
    content_tag(:div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}",:class=>"alert alert-danger") do 
        "#{msg}".html_safe  
    end     
  end
  flash.discard
  response
end
```

**create js file to show flash messages using id/class selector such as
.....ajax_flash_error.js.erb**

```
  <% if type==  "User" %>

     $('#flash_user').html("<%= escape_javascript raw(flash_display) %>");

     <% else %>

     $('#common_flash').html("<%= escape_javascript raw(flash_display) %>");
    <%end%>
```

**send the flash message from controllers in usual manner such as 
users_controller.rb**

```
def create
    if user
      //do comething
      else
        respond_to do |format|  
            flash.now[:error]="You cannot edit this Image"
            format.js { render 'shared/ajax_flash_error',:locals=>{:type=>"User"}}
       end  
   end      
end
```

**show flash message in layout or any view file....
application.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="common_flash">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= msg%>
  <%end%>
</div>

####some other view file,use other flash id
<div id="flash_user">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= msg%>
  <%end%>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**In this way you can use multiple divs with unique id/class and show flash messages wherever you want throughout application**

...HOPE IT HELPS**